# How to get multiple products with product ids through Shopify API Gem

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to get multiple products through Shopify API Gem.

I know how to retrieve one product at a time ShopifyAPI::Product.find(product_id).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that has worked for a million times over ...

```
page = 1
count = ShopifyAPI::Product.count
puts "Found #{count} products in Shopify"
if count > 0
  product_details = []
  page += count.divmod(250).first
  while page > 0
    products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: {limit: 250, page: page})
    product_details += products.collect {|p| {id: p.id, title: p.title, handle: p.handle, product_type: p.product_type}}
    page -= 1
  end
end
puts "Processing #{product_details.length} products from Shopify..."
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ShopifyAPI:: Product.find(:all, params: {ids: "1,2,3,4"}) #add other filter as needed....
```