# How to set all products to untaxable in Shopify using the shopify_api Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, shopify

I need to set 10,000+ product variants to untaxable in Shopify using the `shopify_api` Ruby gem.

I have tried:

```
irb(main):001:0> ShopifyAPI::Variant.update_all(taxable: false)
```

but I get the error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `update_all' for ShopifyAPI::Variant:Class
    from (irb):1
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/shopify_api_console-2.0.0/lib/shopify_api_console/console.rb:156:in `launch_shell'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/shopify_api_console-2.0.0/lib/shopify_api_console/console.rb:113:in `console'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/shopify_api_console-2.0.0/bin/shopify-api:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/shopify-api:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/shopify-api:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

`shopify_app` gem uses [`Active Resource`](https://github.com/rails/activeresource).
You can check its wiki to see what methods are supported (`update_all` is not one of them). As far as I know (but I am relatively new to using Shopify) you can not bulk update 10.000 products. There is inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation, but it is for inventory only.

You have to make multiple calls and have to mind shopify's [rate limiting](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/understanding-api-rate-limits).

To update product variants, try this:

```
page = 1
count = ShopifyAPI::Product.count
# Get total number of products
if count > 0
  page += count.divmod(250).first
  while page > 0
    products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: {limit: 250, page: page})

    products.each do |p|
      product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(p.id)
      product.variants.each do |v|
        v.taxable = false
      end
      product.save
    end

    page -= 1
  end
end
```

As of `2019-10` API version this is how you should paginate results:

```
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 50 })

while products.next_page?
  products = products.fetch_next_page
  products.each do |p|
    product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(p.id)
    product.variants.each do |v|
      v.taxable = false
    end
    product.save
  end
end
```

I think this will update a product with all its variant. Using [David's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210841/david-lazar) comment and [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25464553/2612135).

Comment: That loop is not going to work as it stops after 250 products. To do all your products, you inspect the response header and extract the paging parameters and use those to page through your products.

Comment: @DavidLazar thanks for the heads up! How about now?

Comment: That code is obsolete and will likely stop working anytime soon. You need to use paging. It takes very little effort to adjust to paging and you'll benefit with code that will work a lot longer. 

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/paginated-rest-results

Comment: @DavidLazar I have updated my answer. Is that how you would go about implementing this?

Comment: No... see my answer. Your code is calling products you already fetched ensuring this will be super slow as molasses.

Answer (score 1):

This code is better...

```
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all)
process_products(products) 
while products.next_page? 
  products = products.fetch_next_page 
  process_products(products) 
end 

def process_products(products) 
  products.each do |product| 
    # do something with product 
  end 
rescue StandardError => e 
  puts "Process failed #{e.message} #{e.backtrace}" 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to iterate over a collection. I think this should work, and to avoid api rate limit you can sleep every 1000 calls.

```
variants = ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(:all)
variants.each_with_index do |v, call_counter|
  if call_counter % 1000 == 0
    sleep 1 # sleep 1 second every 1000 calls
  end
  v.taxable = false
  v.save
end
```